# using different template parameters in a class

Tags: c++, templates

Are the parameters of a template allowed to be different for different functions of a class? For example, if I had a class:

```
template <class T, class Comparator>
class example {
public: 
void shift(std::vector<T>& a, T low, T, high);
void heapSort(std::vector<T>& a, T size, Comparator comp);
};
```

Am I allowed to do this:

```
template <class T>
void example::shift(std::vector<T>& a, T low, T, high)
```

and:

```
template <class T, class Comparator>
void example::heapSort(std::vector<T>& a, T size, Comparator comp)
```

since the shift function does not require a Comparator type?

Comment: Yes, but it would be more readable to use a different letter than `T`. (and would allow you to use both the original T and the new template parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to make `heapSort` a template function with its own `Comparator` template parameter:

```
template <class T>
class example {
public:
    void shift(std::vector<T>& a, T low, T high);

    template <class Comparator>
    void heapSort(std::vector<T>& a, T size, Comparator comp);
};

template <class T>
void example<T>::shift(std::vector<T>& a, T low, T high) {
    // ...
}

template <class T>
template <class Comparator>
void example<T>::heapSort(std::vector<T>& a, T size, Comparator comp) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that the definition of `heapSort` has two `template` lines — one for the class, one for the function.  It's a template within a template.

Comment: This worked. I just don't understand the syntax of templates very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to do this since your function may access class members and these may depend on the template parameter. You can use a shorter name though for the unused parameter, or maybe even omits its name and only leave 'class'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you actually want is:

```
template <class T, class Comp1>
class example {
public: 
    void shift(std::vector<T>& a, T low, T, high); // uses Comp1

    template<class Comp2>
    void heapSort(std::vector<T>& a, T size, Comp2 comp);
};
```

Comment: Actually one of the functions (the shift function) doesn't use the comp  parameter, which is why I'm so confused. Only the heapSort function requires a Comparator object. Then, do I need to proceed every function with template <class T, class Comparator> ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand template parameters. The `T` and `Comp1` are parameters **of example**, i.e. when used later, it is `example<T, Comp1>`. Any members of `example<T, Comp1>` have access to `T` and `Comp1`. They don't have to use them if they don't want to.   `Comp2` however, is just a parameter of `heapSort`, i.e. it is `example<T, Comp1>::heapSort<Comp2>` .

Comment: what is Comp1 used for?

Comment: I think OP's point is that `example` doesn't need the `Comp1` parameter; it only needs `T`.